I cant manage my extensions even if I am admin user in typo3
I am using ddev based typo3 project and I cant manage my extensions, I cant find the get extensions, activate or any other action even if I am admin user
I looked in a lot of typo3 issues and dindt find the same problem and also the docs and gpt didnt help

Do you have a symlinked installation or a composer-based?
https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/tutorial-getting-started/11.5/en-us/Extensions/Management.html#extensions_management

A composer-based

you've installed typo3/cms-extensionmanager?

Beside that, some users even avoid installing the extension manager, as they know about installed extensions just by the composer.json. The extension manager doesn't have a functional aspect but serves only for information in composer based installations.

Since your installation is based on composer, the only things left to the extension manager are to show a list of available and installed extensions and to provide possible actions assigned to those extensions.
So you can for example download the code as a zip file or execute a specific update script.
Anything else has to be done with composer, because otherwise you would be able to break the installation that was provided via composer.json and composer.lock
